# Xamarin.Android Deployment Error using Android Virtual Device

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, android-emulator

I am trying to setup a development environment in Visual Studio Community for development with Xamarin.Forms. In order to make sure the Android Emulator was working, I followed the QuickStart Xamarin.Android tutorial found [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/).
When I Start Debugging with any number of Virtual Devices the output is always the same; the application does not show up, but the AVD successfully starts up and I can also successfully interact with OS; when trying the close the AVD (with the x icon on the top right) a pop-up dialog appears saying "There were Deployment Errors. Do you wish to continue? Yes\No". The frustrating part is that no matter my response there is absolutely no useful error informations, or warnings or messages for that matter. You may think this is a duplicate question but it is not. I have had problems with a similar problem in which the fix was to downgrade my Android SDK BuildTools to a version lower than 24.0. The was to circumvent an upstream bug that provided the error message: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError blah blah blah. The problem here is I get NO error and my highest version Build Tools are version 23.0.3 which should be fine. Here is a pic on start-up:

[AVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLscL.png)

Unfortunately as I am only a begginer user I am not permitted to post more links and images. Apologies for the images as links I am still only permitted to post images in this way.

Thank you for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: look at the output window. You will definitely find a vague exception there. I think you have a runtime error which prevents your application showing its main activity. share the output error.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. That's my whole issue, there is nothing in the output window. Like I previously stated the only sign of error is the application not starting and the Pop-up window. I would have sent a screen shot of the error list but there are no errors under the error list.

Comment: Once I had the same problem. It seemed that it had been stuck through the building operation. I stopped the building (Build > Cancel), rebuild the solution and started the app again. It was fixed and showed the activity

Comment: I rebuilt the solution before starting debugging? I have cancelled and rebuilt multiple times. This is continuous I have attempted to debug and have Rebuilt multiple times.

Comment: I'd like to take a look at your OnCreate method. Did you manipulate it?

Comment: I appreciate you help but I don't think that is the answer. When i asked the question i sent a link to the tutorial I was following. I am learning Xamarin.Forms but i wanted to make sure AVDs were all good so I created a Xamarin.Android (Blank App) the code is literally copy and pasted from that tutorial. I doubt the problem is with that code but just check the tutorial code if you are certain. its going to be more readable than a screenshot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Hi anyone with a similar problem, this is what worked for me in this particular case. I started the AVD before starting Debugging, the application then showed up in the emulators device menu and everthing is working. I have been stuck with this problem for Five whole day trying dozens of things. Pheeeeuuuuuuw!